# Unable to get custom error message from AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, servlets

i am trying to edit my shopping cart through AJAX , once i click on edit , it checks the items in `STOCK` , if stock is there it changes the cart and i get the message , but if stock is less , i dont get the custom message , so the point is , i am only able to get **success** and **error**(internal server error) message and unable to get the custom message for less stock

jquery code :

```
$.ajax({
             type:     "post",
             url:      "/devilmaycry/register?action=editcart",
             data:     {pid:pid,quant:quant,spid:spid,cartid:cartid},
             success:  
                   function() 
                    {
                        if (xhr.responseText=="less stock")
                            alert("Stock is less");
                        else
                         alert("Item quantity has been changed in cart");
                    },
                  error:
                     function(xhr) 
                      {
                           if(xhr.responseText=="Internal server error")
                            alert("item cannot be added , internal server error");
                      } 
              }); 
             return false; 
         });
```

servlet code :

```
else if(n.equals("editcart"))
  {
      int pid = Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("pid"));
      int spid = Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("spid"));
      int cartid = Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("cartid"));
      int quant = Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("quant"));


      k=o.editcart(cartid,pid,spid,quant);

     if(k==2)
      {
        res.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_ACCEPTED);
        pw.write("less stock");
      } 
     else if(k==0)
      {
        res.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        pw.write("Internal server error");          
      }
  }

i haven't introduced the database logic because i have checked and it is working fine
```

Comment: What are you getting in xhr.responseText?

Comment: @prashanth i didnt get you fully but from what i understand , you are asking about alerts , so when stock is good , i get item changed in stock , when there is internal server error , i get error message but when stock is less i still get success alert

Comment: You haven't loaded `xhr` in `success` as parameter for anonymous function, then where are you getting `xhr` in `if (xhr.responseText=="less stock")` from?  You need to pass it as `success : function(xhr){ ... }`

Comment: did that , still gives the success alert ..`Item quantity has been changed in cart`